Azure pipelines reference repository variable for an if statement in variables template
I'm creating a pipeline for some of my microservices.
To centralize and standardize, I created a Repo just for the pipelines. That said, I have a problem regarding variables that are filled in at runtime and the IF condition is performed at compile time.
Here are example yamls:
Pipeline:
trigger: none

pool: "PrivPool"

resources:
  repositories:   
    - repository: DeployingRepo
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/development
      name: MyPoject/MyRepo
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - staging

variables:
  - template: /variables/variables.yaml

stages:
  - stage: Test
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
          - bash: |
              echo "var = $(envVar)"


Variable template example:
variables:
  - name: isMaster
    value: $[eq(resources.repositories['DeployingRepo'].ref, 'refs/heads/master')]
  - name: isStaging
    value: $[eq(resources.repositories['DeployingRepo'].ref, 'refs/heads/staging')]

  - ${{ if eq(variables.isMaster, true) }}:
    - name: envVar
      value: 'Production'

  - ${{ elseif eq(variables.isStaging, true) }}:
    - name: envVar
      value: 'Staging'

  - ${{ else }}:
    - name: envVar
      value: 'Dev'

This example represents well what I need to do
Is there a way to force IF to run at runtime, or any other way to make it work?

Question: Is there a way to force ${{ if ... }} to run at runtime? Answer: No

@RuiJarimba I already suspected there was no way... Do you have any idea how to do this another way?

I think your best option here is to use the setvariable logging command to set a pipeline variable that can be used in the following tasks.
Example:
resources:
  repositories:   
    - repository: DeployingRepo
      type: git
      name: MyPoject/MyRepo
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - staging
            - development

variables:
  - name: branch
    value: $[resources.repositories.DeployingRepo.ref]

stages:
  - stage: Test
    jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: 'Test job'
        steps:
          - script: |
              BRANCH="$(branch)"
              echo "Current branch: $BRANCH"

              if [ "$BRANCH" == "refs/heads/main" ]; then
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=envVar]Production"
              elif [ "$BRANCH" == "refs/heads/master" ]; then
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=envVar]Production"
              elif [ "$BRANCH" == "refs/heads/staging" ]; then
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=envVar]Staging"
              else
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=envVar]Dev"
              fi
            displayName: 'Set pipeline variable'
          - script: |
              echo "environment: $(envVar)"
            displayName: 'Display variable'

Note: When you add a variable with task.setvariable, the following tasks can use the variable using macro syntax $(myVar). The variable will only be available to tasks in the same job by default.
If you add the parameter isoutput, the syntax to call your variable changes. See Levels of output variables to determine the appropriate syntax for each use case.
